# Unimodular element of a module

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, projective-module

Let $A$ be a noetherian ring and $M$ an $A$-module. An element $z \in M$ is said to be unimodular if $Az$ is a direct summand of $M$ and $Ann(z) = \{r \in A | rz=0\} = 0$. The order ideal of $M$ is:  $O_M(z)=\{\phi(z)| \phi  \in Hom_A(M,A)\}$.

Now the author says that an element $z \in M$  is unimodular if and only if $O_M(z)=A$. I think we need to think in terms of surjection to prove this result but I don't know exactly how should I proceed. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo, the correct definition is “*An element $z \in M$ is unimodular if $\operatorname{Ann}(z)=\{a \in A : az=0\}$ **is zero** and $Az$ is a direct summand of $M$*”.

Here are some ideas, I hope you can connect them and finish the proof from this.

- Assuming that $\operatorname{Ann}(z)=0$, $Az$ is a direct summand of $M$ if and only if the monomorphism $A \to M$, $a \mapsto az$ splits.
- The ideal $O_M(z)$ is $A$ if and only if $1 \in O_M(z)$.

Comment: Assuming that z is unimodular tells us that the map say $\phi : A \longrightarrow M$ given by $a \mapsto az$ splits. This tells us that there exists a map say $\psi: M \longrightarrow A$ such that $\psi \circ \phi = Id_A $. And thus we get $\psi(z) =1$. Now assuming $O_M(z)=A$, we know that there exists a map $\psi:M\longrightarrow  A$ such that $\psi(z)=1$. This tells us that $\psi$ is surjective and since $Az \cong A$, we have $M \cong  Az \bigoplus N$ for some module $N$. Is this correct?

Comment: @RudreshKumbargire I think it is, but I don’t fully understand the second implication. From $\psi \colon M \to A$ with $\psi(z)=1$, prove that $\psi \circ \phi = \operatorname{id}_A$. This gives us that $\phi$ is injective, and then $\operatorname{Ann}(z) = \ker \phi = 0$. Finally, prove that $M = Az \oplus \ker \psi$, that is, prove that $M = Az + \ker \psi$ and $Az \cap \ker \psi = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have another doubt regarding order ideals. If we have $f=(f_1,f_2) \in A^2=F$, how should I show that $O_F(f)=Af_1+Af_2$. I tried constructing a map from $Af_1+Af_2$ to $O_F(f)$ but was not able to contruct an isomorphism. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @RudreshKumbargire You’re welcome. Well, how do the elements of $\operatorname{Hom}_A(F,A)$ look like? As one in linear algebra proves, every $\phi \in \operatorname{Hom}_A(F,A)$ is of the form $\phi(x_1,x_2) = a_1x_1+a_2x_2$ for some $a_1,a_2 \in A$. Hence $O_F(f) = \{\phi(f_1,f_2) : \phi \in \operatorname{Hom}_A(F,A) \} = \cdots$